# Facebook showing fatal error in php sdk

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

What is meant by the below error?Why am i getting this.

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected end of query. thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1039

I'm using a code to delete the invite once the user clicks on it from app tab,but this is not deleting the app request

Here is the code,

```
   foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)
    {
     echo ("reqeust_id=".$request_id."<br>");
    $full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id);  
     echo ("full_request_id=".$full_request_id."<br>");

  try {
     $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
     if ($delete_success) {
        echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
     else {
       echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
    }          
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  echo "error";}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is this bit in quotes?

```
$facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
```

Surely it should just be:

```
$facebook->api($full_request_id,'DELETE');
```

Other than that I see nothing wrong with your code. Although, it would be good to know what line 1039 in base_facebook.php is.

Comment: :I've not added any thing new into php sdk.It is the default one,i down loaded it from git hub.I corrected it but still it is not deleting